# neo4j fails to start on linux node

Tags: linux, neo4j

brought over install files to my linux server.  But when I go to run it I get some weird errors

```
[user@server neo4j-community-1.9.M04]$ sudo ./bin/neo4j start
./bin/neo4j: line 54: cd: /home/afrieden/neo4j-community-1.9.M04: Permission denied
./bin/neo4j: line 70: bin/utils: No such file or directory
./bin/neo4j: line 65: getconfig: command not found
./bin/neo4j: line 66: getconfig: command not found
./bin/neo4j: line 151: detectos: command not found
./bin/neo4j: line 152: exitonnojava: command not found
./bin/neo4j: line 153: checkstatus: command not found
./bin/neo4j: line 154: checklimits: command not found
./bin/neo4j: line 156: checkjvmcompatibility: command not found
Another server-process is running with [4523], cannot start a new one. Exiting.
```

Still learning a lot of this.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't own `/home/afrieden/neo4j-community-1.9.M04`. Try to change ownership:

```
sudo chown -R afrieden:users /home/afrieden/neo4j-community-1.9.M04
```

Comment: also, there is no need to run the `./neo4j start` with sudo permissions.